# How to bind multiple routing keys to queue in Ruby AMQP?

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, amqp

Is there a way to specify multiple keys. I know in the rabbitmq web interface I can specify multiple routing keys for a queue. Is there a way to do this programmatically in AMQP gem.

Is it possibile to use something like this `queue.bind(exchange, :routing_key => [ 'key_name1.*', 'key_name2.*'])`.

Answer (score 0):

Just perform many calls to `queue.bind` in your code, one after the other with the particular routing key that you want to use.